# What the regex pattern (in c#) I must use for this?

Tags: c#, regex

I have a url like this:

`http://www.localhostserver.com/appserver/key=***b0U%2fPzc%2fPzsPy***/photo.jpg`

I want the string between `key=` and `/photo.jpg`

Thanks

Comment: That would be quite easy if you just did some research of your own regarding regular expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one:

```
key=(.*?)/photo.jpg
```